# can you define this set?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I have troubles finding a set of numbers which are in the set $ M \subset \mathbb R^2$ which is made up of $(x,y)\in\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, which satisfy the conditions $ x\leq 4$ and $y\leq 4$. I can't solve the entire task unless I try to figure out what's in that set, which I tried, but with no success.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking at a specific intersection $M=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}|x\leq 4,y \leq4\}\cap\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}=\{(x,y)|x,y \in \{1,2,3,4\}\}.$

Comment: What should I do with this R^2?

Comment: $\mathbb{R^2}=\{(x,y)|x,y\in\mathbb{R}\}$

Comment: @ellya: this is much better than my set +1.

Comment: Why did you ignore 0 and the negative numbers?

Comment: because the $(x,y)$ we are looking for are also in $\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N}$, which means that $x,y\in\{1,2,3...\}$ so $0$ and negative numbers are missed out.

Comment: It seems to me that it's more standard to include $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$. But the adjustment needed here is pretty trivial.

Comment: No that's wrong

Comment: Just to say  $\mathbb {N}$ is the set of natural numbers, that's why we don't include $0$ since when numbers and counting started off, there was no physical relevance for the number 0

Answer (score 2):

$A=\{(x,y) \in \textbf{R}^2|x\leq 4, y\leq 4$, where $ x,y \in \mathbb{N} \}$